# how to call a server-side ASP.NET event from the client-side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net button in the gridview footer, and I wanna to call the server-side ASP.NET button event in the client side (JavaScript).

How to do this please code details if possible.

**My .aspx:**

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_add" ImageUrl="~/Images/accord_plus.png" 
         runat="server" OnClick="ibtn_add_Click" />
</FooterTemplate>
```

I wanna to know how to call the `ibtn_add_Click` in the client side.

in the following code:

```
var isShift = false;
document.onkeyup = function(e)
{ if (e.which == 16) isShift = false; }
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 16) isShift = true;
    if (e.which == 13 && isShift == true) {
        //Here I wanna to call ibtn_add_Click
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

**Note :**

The gridview in an update panel, and I execute the JavaScript through:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Shortcut.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Where is the problem?? If you want to call function `ibtn_add_Click`, then call it `ibtn_add_Click()`

Comment: Or you want to trigger onclick server handler?

Comment: I think, it is not good practice to call server handler `OnClick` if click was not really performed. Think about sending PostBack or Ajax call.

Comment: please more clarification ,the gridview in an update panel and i do the following:

Comment: `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
   
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Shortcut.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnClientClick` button's attribute.

```
OnClientClick="ibtn_add_Click()"
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx)

Comment: hmmm i wanna to call it under specific condition in my javascript code

Comment: explain, please your "specific condition"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this ...

```
if (e.which == 13 && isShift == true) 
{ 
    __doPostBack('ibtn_add','OnClick');
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use ajax and make a call to webservice or web method or you can use or you can use

```
 __doPostBack(‘btntest','OnClick')
```

or

```
 $('btntest').trigger('click');
```

chck this link : http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/some-tricks-for-asynchronous-postback.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn_add" ImageUrl="~/Images/accord_plus.png" runat="server" OnClick="ibtn_add_Click" />
```

This is the problem I have faced but I used only for `OnClientClick`